# Unable to add netflix-hystrix dependency without a version number to POM.XML

Tags: spring, hystrix

When I try to add the dependency of netflix-hystrix in my pom.xml without a version number for the framework to download the latest version, the system is unable to recognize the dependency. I get the following message
`Cannot resolve org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:unknown`

However when I add a version number `<version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>` the system recognizes the dependency. Any idea why this happens? as it now ties the version in the dependency and will not upgrade automatically to the new version when released.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807480/springboot-hystrixnulljar-the-version-cannot-be-empty

Comment: Yes, it looks like the same questions, thanks